# Expand sum over product

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, real-numbers

Let $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{b_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be sequences of real numbers. Is there a simple formula to expand:

\begin{equation*}
\prod_{i=1}^n(a_i+b_i)
\end{equation*}

To get a sense of the type of formula I want, consider:

\begin{equation*}
(\sum_{i=1}^na_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 + 2\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}a_ia_j
\end{equation*}

I attempted to expand the product but I am not getting satisfactory results organized in a way that is simple enough to use.

Comment: $\sum\limits_{\Delta\subset [n]}\prod\limits_{i\in \Delta}a_i\prod\limits_{i\in [n]\setminus\Delta}b_i$.  That is to say, each index $i$ appears exactly once in each term in the result and each sequence of alternating between $a$ and $b$ appears.

Comment: For an example, when $n=3$ this would expand as $a_1a_2a_3+a_1a_2b_3+a_1b_2a_3+b_1a_2a_3+a_1b_2b_3+b_1a_2b_3+b_1b_2a_3+b_1b_2b_3$

Comment: Let $S$ be a subset of the index set $1,2,\dots,n$, and denote by $\Pi(S,a)$ the product of all $a$ terms of the $a$-sequence that correspond to indices in $S$. Use similar notation for the $b$-products. For an index set $S$ as above denote by $S'$ the complement. Then the wanted product is in full expansion the sum $$\sum_S\Pi(S,a)\cdot \Pi(S',b)\ ,$$where $S$ runs in the $2^n$ subsets of the index set. - Same answer as above.